# Disabling the elements in the NavigationView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    signUpPageButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = binding.personName.text.toString()
        val surname = binding.personSurname.text.toString()
        val email = binding.personEmail.text.toString()
        val password = binding.personPassword.text.toString()

        if (name.equals("") || surname.equals("") || email.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Lütfen Tüm Alanları Doldurun.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
      else  if  (radioButtonAccept.isChecked){
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener {
                val action = SignUpFragmentDirections.actionSignUpFragmentToSignUpCalculateFragment()
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
        else  if (radioButtonDenied.isChecked){
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener {
                val action = SignUpFragmentDirections.actionSignUpFragmentToCalculateFragment()
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            val nav: NavController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment)
           navController.menu.(R.id.panelFragment).isEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

There are 2 buttons on my register page. If the user registers by pressing the 2nd button, I want to prevent the clicking of some elements in the navigationView on my homepage.

So, I wrote this code in the last two lines but it didn't work.

```
val nav: NavController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment)
               navController.menu.(R.id.panelFragment).isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
val nav: NavController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment)
       navController.menu.(R.id.panelFragment).isEnabled = false
```

put a variable Boolean available = true where you will save are the menu items available. In java
synchronize(available) {available = false;}
Then you need to set a listener on navigationView items like

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
synchronize(available) {
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu && !available)
    return false; //return that menu item is not selected
navController.navigate(item.getItemId());
return true;    
}});
```